# Groovy Oracle Stored Proc - invaid column index

Tags: oracle, jdbc, groovy

```
sql.call("StoredProcName", [Sql.resultSet(OracleTypes.CURSOR)]) { table ->
        table.eachRow { row->
            println row
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
This block of code is throwing me a  `invalid column index`

This code looks the same as examples that I've seen online. What am I missing? Can I not do eachRow on a cursor? Here is my proc

```
Create or Replace Procedure StoredProcName(cursor_ OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
as
Begin
Open cursor_ For
Select blahblahblah
```

Comment: Have you tried `resultSet` with a capital S as in the [documentation](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#resultSet-int-)

Comment: Thanks Tim! I've updated my question, which I think now is a better question, since you fixed my syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code can help you get variable of `SYS_REFCURSOR` from Oracle anonymous block.

We should focus on a few key details:

1. Class `groovy.sql.Sql` doesn't have corresponding `OutParameter` and we make it manually as `CURSOR_PARAMETER` and pass it to `sql.call` method
2. Consider that the block starts with `{call DECLARE` and ends with `END }` without semicolon after END. Otherwise we can get a poorly recognizable `SQLException` in the face.
3. The question marks `?` inside the `sqlString` are places for parameter bindings. Bindings are made in the natural order taking values from `parametersList`.

   - In this example we have the only binding, so the `?` binds with CURSOR_PARAMETER treating the value as `OUT` parameter of passed type;
4. There is only one enter into closure after `sql.call` and `ResultSet rs` provide rows of cursor `my_cur` declared in anonymous block.
5. We can simplify `sqlString` by using a function returning `SYS_REFCURSOR` unstead of a procedure with `OUT` parameter. So it could look like this `"{call BEGIN ? := MY_FUNC(); END}"` or even `"{? = call MY_FUNC()}"`

---

```
import groovy.sql.OutParameter
import groovy.sql.Sql
import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes

import java.sql.ResultSet

def driver = 'oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver'
def sql = Sql.newInstance('jdbc:oracle:thin:@my-server:1521:XXX', 'usr', 'psw', driver)

// special OutParameter for cursor type
OutParameter CURSOR_PARAMETER = new OutParameter() {
    public int getType() {
        return OracleTypes.CURSOR;
    }
};

// look at some ceremonial wrappers around anonymous block
String sqlString = """{call
    DECLARE
      my_cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
    BEGIN
        STORED_PROCEDURE_NAME(my_cur);
        ? := my_cur;
    END
}
""";

// the order of elements matches the order of bindings
def parametersList = [CURSOR_PARAMETER];


// rs contains the result set of cursor my_cur
sql.call(sqlString, parametersList) { ResultSet rs ->
  while (rs.next()) {
      println rs.getString("my_column")
  }
};
```

P.S. And thank you for the question.

Comment: Awesome, you're a lifesaver!

Comment: It can also be written a bit more succinctly like this
sql.call(sqlString, [Sql.out(OracleTypes.CURSOR)])